# How to restart service when it get stopped in Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, service

This question might be repeated, but I get confuse how to do it.

I have one java project with .jar file.
Now I want to run this project in background independent of console.

Means want to make a service that can be START servicename and STOP servicename,
and also when service get stopped it will automatically restart.

Now I made only one shell script as " java -cp  abc.jar filename & "
and stopping server just kill that port number.

So please suggest me the proper way to make service from .jar file and how it will get restarted automatically after stopped.

Edit : Actually my server on linux is not stopped its just unresponsive because at client side when it shows server connection error, server is still running means port number is still in LIST mode.

Should I increase the ulimit ?

Comment: (Be sure to read the comments there, no just the answers.)

Comment: but I want my service will get automatically restarted when it get stopped.

Comment: That's why I said to be sure to read the comments. :-) First comment on the question is one way: http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html This may also be useful: http://serverfault.com/questions/252137/how-to-automatically-restart-a-service-on-failure-in-linux

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Please read edited question plz.

Comment: That's a different question. I'd suggest deleting this one and asking that one.